# best-practice on for loop's condition

Tags: for-loop, compilation, compile-time

what is considered best-practice in this case?

```
for (i=0; i<array.length(); ++i)
```

or

```
for (i=array.length()-1; i>=0; --i)
```

assuming i don't want to iterate from a certain direction, but rather over the bare length of the array. also, i don't plan to alter the array's size in the loop body.

so, will the `array.length()` become constant during compilation? if not, then the second approach should be the one to go for..

Comment: The fact that you got the version2 wrong says something. Doesn't it?

Comment: It depends on the language, as well.  If `i` is unsigned, you're going to have trouble getting the termination condition right on the down counting version.  (It's already wrong, even if `i` is signed.)

Comment: Wouldn't ++i result in out of bounds on the last pass?

Comment: pre/post increment matters little in the for loop as it is executed by itself when flow control hits the ending brace.  No difference (with ints) between ++i;  and i++; on lines by themselves in code.  There can be a difference with classes and pre/post increment and copy constructors so beware there.

Answer (score 1):

Version 2 is broken and would iterate from one past end of array to 1. *(Now corrected)*

Stick with version 1. It's well recognised and doesn't leave the reader doing a double-take.

Comment: Depending on the language, version 2 can still be broken! For instance, when array.Length is 0 and i is an unsigned integer. Classic integer underflow.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the first method, as that is much more readable, and I can look and see you are iterating over the loop. The second one took me a second :(.

`array.length` will remain constant so long as you arent modifying the array.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1 is far more widely used and simpler to understand. Version 2 may occasionally be very slightly faster if the compiler doesn't optimize array.length() into a constant, but...`insert your own premature optimization comment here`

EDIT: as to whether array.length() will be optimized out, it will depend on the language. If the language uses arrays as "normal" objects or arrays can be dynamically sized, it will be just a method call and the compiler can't assume will return a consistent return value. But for languages in which arrays are a special case or object (or the compiler's just really smart...) the speed difference will probably be eliminated.

Comment: +1 for mention of premature optimisation. The clearest approach IS the best approach until it's found to cause problems.

Comment: but `array.length()` could not be known given dynamic sized arrays

Answer (score 1):

In most cases I would expect `array.length()` to be implemented in such a way that it is O(1), so it would not really impact on the loop's performance. If you are in doubt, or want to make sure it is a constant, just do so explicitly:

```
// JavaScript
var l = a.length;

for (var i=0; i<l; i++) {
  // do something
}
```

I consider the reversed notation a "clever hack" that falls into the premature optimization category. It's harder to read, more error-prone and does not really provide a benefit over the alternative I suggest.

But since implementations of compilers/interpreters are vastly different and you do not say what language you refer to, it is hard to make an absolute statement about this. I would say unless this is in an absolutely time-critical section of code or otherwise measurably contributing to code running time, and your benchmark tests show that doing it differently provides a real benefit, I would stick to the code that's easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

`for (i=0; i<array.length(); ++i)` is better for me, but `for (i=array.length()-1; i>=0; --i)` is fastest, because common processors fastest checking condition comparing to 0 to condition comparing to two varbiales.

`array.lenght()` is constant if you dont adding/erasing elements from this array under iterations.

Comment: Fastest would depend upon the language being used

Comment: If you're accessing items in a zero-index array you actually want `for (i = array.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)`.

Comment: @Jeff could you elaborate? which languages (e.g.) wouldn't be bothered by choosing one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

For a for loop in my own code, though it's probably overkill, I got into the habit early on of writing my loops such that the length gets calculated exactly once, but the loop proceeds in the natural way:

```
int len = array.length();
for (int i=0; i<len; ++i) {
    doSomething(array[i]);
}
```

These days, though, I prefer using "for-each" facilities where they're available and convenient; they make loops easier to read and foolproof. In C++ that would be something like:

```
std::for_each(array.begin(), array.end(), &doSomething);
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 1 is quickest. for (i=0; i